# Track m2m update fields in Django

Tags: python, django, signals

I'm trying to track m2m change with signal to create activity history, I'm using [django activity stream](http://django-activity-stream.readthedocs.org/)

I have tried to use pre_save signals and compare the origin and actual states of the field, but for a reason I can't understand my field is at None even when it contains information, here is the code

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Artwork)
def artwork_update_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    orig = Artwork.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
    print (orig.collectors)
    print (instance.collectors)
    if orig.collectors != instance.collectors:
        print ("collectors diff")
```

I have also tried to use m2m_changed signals, but signals are sent even when updating an other field in the models and I can't know which fields are update

Answer (score 0):

It's not that easy to track m2m changes. I did have similar requirement before, what I ended up doing is using [django simple history](https://github.com/treyhunner/django-simple-history) package. It's a package that simply track all changes on model objects(create, update, delete). However, m2m fields do not explicitly exist for normal cases, so I added a [through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) model just for history tracking. It might be overkill depend on how bad do you want this feature, but it definitely worth go give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

m2m fields send 2 signals on save: 'pre_add', 'post_add', 'pre_remove', 'post_remove'. There is no pre_save.

Therefore it will look something like this:

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Artwork.the_m2m_field.through)
def artwork_update_handler(sender, instance, action, model, pk_set, **kwargs):
    if action == 'pre_save':
        orig = Artwork.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
        print (orig.collectors)
        print (instance.collectors)
        if orig.collectors != instance.collectors:
            print ("collectors diff")
```